# cannot find jars for the imported Giraph packages

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, giraph

I was trying to run the SSSP giraph program from Eclipse. But I couldnt get the following packages imported

```
import org.apache.giraph.graph.BasicVertex;
import org.apache.giraph.graph.BspUtils;
import org.apache.giraph.graph.GiraphJob;
import org.apache.giraph.graph.EdgeListVertex;
import org.apache.giraph.graph.VertexReader;
import org.apache.giraph.graph.VertexWriter;
import org.apache.giraph.lib.TextVertexInputFormat;
import org.apache.giraph.lib.TextVertexInputFormat.TextVertexReader;
import org.apache.giraph.lib.TextVertexOutputFormat;
import org.apache.giraph.lib.TextVertexOutputFormat.TextVertexWriter;
```

I have followed the instruction in the giraph site to build Giraph and Hadoop.
Which jar should be imported to get the above packages?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the code for the correct version of Giraph?  I think the imports you mention are for versions before 1.0.0, if you include a jar for a newer version it won't find them.